# Multithreading row search

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm

Let us suppose I have the following data:

```
first        last           age           country
tom          keller         10            us
lewis        smith          20            us
cindy        jones          30            us
brad         hart           40            ca
```

And I want to do an `edge` search based on multiple fields. For example, searching for `"tom kel us"` would return the first row. A basic/trivial algorithm for this would be:

```
search = "tom kel us"
data = [
    {"first": "tom", "last": "keller", "age": 10, "country": "us"},
    {"first": "lewis", "last": "smith", "age": 20, "country": "us"},
    {"first": "cindy", "last": "jones", "age": 30, "country": "us"},
    {"first": "brad", "last": "hart", "age": 40, "country": "ca"}   
]
fields = data[0].keys()
matches = []
for row in data:
    match = True
    for term in search.split():
        if not any([str(row[field] or '').startswith(term) for field in fields]):
            match = False
    if match: matches.append(row)

>>> matches
[{'country': 'us', 'age': 10, 'last': 'keller', 'first': 'tom'}]
```

My question then is what would be an example of how to multi-thread a search algorithm such as the above? Initially I wanted to break it up by columns, but that wouldn't work since the search `chains` all the columns together. My next thought was to take `x` chunks and then slice the data such as `[item for num, item in enumerate(data) if num % X == 0]`. What would be the best way to multi-thread a search algorithm without having to copy a lot of data, etc. The actual data could have about ~ 10M rows or so.

Comment: Do you literally mean "multi-thread"? As there is GIL in Python(Well, in CPython), multi-thread won't take more than one core which causes it is only suitable for IO sensitive tasks. I guess you want to use "multi-process"?

Comment: @Sraw -- I see, would the answer be different if, for example, we were talking about C++ instead?

Comment: Definitely. The threads in C++ can use multiple cores. Actually using multi-thread in Python for a computation sensitive tasks will only slow it down.